# What are the drop shadow parameters for material design shadows?

Tags: gimp, google-material-design

The [material design docs](https://m2.material.io/design/environment/light-shadows.html#light) describe two shadows, one cast by a `key light`, one cast by an `ambient light`.

What are the drop shadow parameters that lead to those shadows for, lets say, a given elevation of `12 dp`?